# cannot get C++ PyArray_SimpleNewFromData to complete

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I have already looked for instructions to do this. I have used import_Array(). I am using Python 3.10 I have the Windows Visual Studio.

this is my code:

```
PyObject* switch_rut(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
PyArrayObject* inp1;
PyArrayObject* inp2;
PyObject* outp;
double swv;

double* res;
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!O!d:switcher", &PyArray_Type, &inp1, &PyArray_Type, &inp2, &swv)) {
    return NULL;
}
if (inp1->nd != 1 || inp1->descr->type_num != PyArray_DOUBLE || inp2->nd != 1 || inp2->descr->type_num != PyArray_DOUBLE || ) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,
        "arrays must be one-dimensional and of type float");
    return NULL;
}
if (inp1->dimensions[0] != inp2->dimensions[0]) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,
        "arrays must be of equal length");
    return NULL;
}
int* cnt = new int[1];
int nd = 1;
cnt[0] = inp1->dimensions[0];
int acnt = inp1->dimensions[0];
res = new double[acnt];
double ipar1, ipar2, iparr;
for (int i = 0; i < acnt; i++) {
    ipar1 = *(double*)(inp1->data + i * inp1->strides[0]);
    ipar2 = *(double*)(inp2->data + i * inp2->strides[0]);
    iparr = ipar2 * swv + ipar1 * (1 - swv);
    res[i] = iparr;
}
outp = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(nd, cnt, NPY_DOUBLE,reinterpret_cast<void*> res);
return outp;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What I was talking about was how to embed Python in C or C++ with Numpy arrays
and how to return a value as a Numpy array.
This is what I used.

```
PyArray_New(&PyArray_Type, nd, bcnt, NPY_DOUBLE, NULL, (void*) res, 0, NPY_ARRAY_CARRAY, NULL);
```